# When is $\sqrt{x}/4$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find out under what conditions for $x$ the expression $\sqrt{x}/4$ is in $\mathbb Z$. So my idea was following:

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x}/4 \in \mathbb Z \\
\iff \sqrt{x} \in 4\mathbb Z \\
\iff  \sqrt{x} = 4n \text{  for some } n \in \mathbb Z   \end{align}\\
\iff x = 16n^2 \text{  for some }n \in \mathbb Z$$

I am not sure about the last step, is that one true?

Comment: The condition is correct.

Comment: @Martigan No, it says 'for _some_ $n\in\Bbb Z$'. The '_some_ $n\in\Bbb Z$' there would be $-n$. We have $\sqrt{x}=4(\pm n)\iff x=16n^2$, and the equivalence is correct.

Comment: Thanks AndréNicolas and user26486!

Comment: @user26486 No, I was talking about the "equivalence". You can't write, in a general sense, that $x=\alpha^2$ is equivalent to $\sqrt x=\alpha$... And in fact that is what you wrote by stating the $\pm$ sign in your comment... Your equivalence is correct, not the OP's. The fact that it is written for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not enough...

Comment: @Martigan Again, it says 'for _some_ $n\in\Bbb Z$'. $\pm n$ is an integer, whether it is $n$ or $-n$.

Comment: @user26486 Perhaps I am nitpicking, but if a student writes to me $x=16n^2 \implies \sqrt x=4n$, I will not be happy...

Comment: @Martigan It explicitly says: '($\sqrt{x}=4n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$)$\iff$ ($x=16n^2$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$)'. It does not say '$\sqrt{x}=4n\iff x=16n^2$'.

Comment: @Martigan: You would be right to, since $n$ is unqualified there.  But if a student wrote: $\sqrt{x} = 4n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow x = 16m^2$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, wouldn't that be right?  And since the scope of the $m$ is restricted to the RHS, it should be fine to replace the $m$ by $n$ there.  One might observe that it could be confusing—hard to dispute that—but it certainly doesn't seem flat out wrong.

Comment: By definition $\sqrt{x}$ is non negative, so everything is technically OK. But it would be clearer to specify on-negative integer instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Here's the proof of the equivalence: $x$ is in the form $16n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$ $\iff$ $\sqrt x/4 \in \mathbb Z$:

- Let $x$ be in form $16n^2$ for some $n$ from $\mathbb Z$. Then, square root of $x$ is either $4n$ or $-4n$ and $x/4$ is either $n$ or $-n$, which is, in any case, in $\mathbb Z$.
- Now, let's take an $x$ such that  $\sqrt x / 4$ is in $\mathbb Z$. We must find an $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that the $x$ is in the form $16n^2$. If we take $n=\sqrt x/4$, then $16n^2 = 16(\sqrt x/4)^2 = 16(x/16) = x$

Comment: Ah now I did not see the first point but now it is obvious, thanks!